# iOS 7 navigation bar height

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Is it possible to change navigation bar height in iOS 7?

why I need navigation bar: 
to have a transparent navigation bar with the right positions of others elements on my view without any problems;

I don't want to create a fake "navigation bar" - in this case I'll need to set up all positions myself.

Answer (score 3):

```
//make real nav bar invisible
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImage* transparentImage = [UIImage emptyImageWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.navigationBar.frame.size.width, 1) andBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:transparentImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = transparentImage;
```

and then

```
UINavigationBar* fakeNavigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,      self.navigationBar.frame.size.width, neededHeight)];
fakeNavigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.navigationBar insertSubview:fakeNavigationBar atIndex:0];
```

where

```
+ (UIImage*)emptyImageWithSize:(CGSize)size andBackgroundColor:(UIColor*)color
{
    CGRect frameRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, color.CGColor); //image frame color
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, frameRect);

    UIImage* resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resultImage;
}
```

Comment: This is creating the send navigation bar in the correct height, but the lower part of it (below the frame of the original navigation bar) is not clickable

Answer (score 1):

In your app delegate

```
UINavigationController *NavController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:HomeViewController];
[NavController.navigationBar setBounds:CGRectMake(10, 30, 40, 10)];
```